# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) C Programming

Tags: c

```
        #include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int firstNum = atoi(argv[1]);
 int secondNum = atoi(argv[2]);
 int sum = firstNum + secondNum;
 printf("%d + %d = %d", firstNum, secondNum, sum);

return 0;
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault. I know what it is, but I can't find where in my code it is. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: Make sure to pass in two arguments to your program.  Perhaps you should check the value of argc to make sure that you have enough elements in the argv array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have as many `argv[]` values as you have command line arguments (and the executable name).

If you run this with no command line arguments, it would segfault because `argv[1]` is invalid.  If you run it with exactly one argument, it will do the same, but at the next line because `argv[2]` is invalid.

You can check the value of `argc` to find out how much of `argv` you can use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int firstNum, secondNum, sum;

  if ( argc != 3 )
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  firstNum = atoi(argv[1]);
  secondNum = atoi(argv[2]);
  sum = firstNum + secondNum;
  printf("%d + %d = %d", firstNum, secondNum, sum);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Remember that `argc` of 1 means no arguments because the first (`argv[0]`) is the name of the executable.

Comment: This cleared a lot up. I appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass 2 arguments, then the program will generate SIGSEGV. If you enter 2 arguments, it should work fine. Also ensure you pass only numbers to get the output, otherwise you will get likely 0 as output. Add an argc check as suggested in the comment to avoid SIGSEGV.